# Rails - add custom index name to add_foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, foreign-keys

I try to add foreign key using `add_foreign_key :questionnaires_pages_redirects, :pages, column: :current_page_id` but got error

`"index name 'index_questionnaires_pages_redirects_on_question_answer_option_id' on table 'questionnaires_pages_redirects' is too long".`

How can I add foreign key with custom index name?

Answer (score 1):

You can try by giving `index name` as in your error it is showing your index name is too long

```
add_index :questionnaires_pages_redirects, :pages, name: "questions_pages_id"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the additional parameter `index: { name: '(set a custom index name here)' }` to your `add_foreign_key` call, like:

```
add_foreign_key :questionnaires_pages_redirects, :pages, column: :current_page_id, index: { name: 'my_index_name' }
```